# .load() or .html() Method wont work in Opera 9

Tags: jquery, image, load

javascript/jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("a").click(function(e){

    var nr = $(this).attr("href").substr(2,3);
    var filename = "images/galerie/martina-flatau"+nr+".png";

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mainview').fadeOut(function() {

        var image = $('<img />').attr('src', filename);       

        image.load(function(){                      
        $('#mainview').html(image).fadeIn();    
        });         

    });     

});
```

});

Question 1:
Some pics (not all!) wont get loaded in Opera 9..I dont know why?

Question 2:
Is there a way to improve the code (even the slightest bit?)

Answer (score 2):

> Some pics (not all!) wont get loaded in Opera 9..I dont know why?

This is because you're setting the `load` event *after* specifying the `src` property. Some images will be loaded before the handler is defined.

Comment: AHA - that works! thx :) ..what is a "handler"? is it the "image" var?

Comment: @Don no, the function that fires on the `load` event.